# Word Search Program for loops not working

Tags: java, arrays, wordsearch

I have this code that will take a word search and find words in it. I got it to work for some things, i tired BINARY and i tried DRAC and it worked, but for some stuff, especially the diagonals, keep giving me outofbounds errors.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class WordSearch { 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner kboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        char[][] maze = {   {'A','P','B','I','N','A','R','Y','D','C','O','C','A','R','D'},
                            {'M','T','C','O','S','M','A','L','L','E','A','A','T','E','B'},
                            {'P','O','E','N','A','M','G','I','S','R','L','N','S','I','R'},
                            {'R','L','D','H','M','A','S','P','I','N','S','T','E','S','T'},
                            {'A','E','A','E','T','G','T','A','B','M','U','H','A','S','G'},
                            {'L','M','G','N','R','E','D','O','O','P','B','E','F','E','H'},
                            {'U','Y','L','O','E','N','O','K','A','L','L','R','A','M','T'},
                            {'C','I','E','V','E','T','E','C','U','N','A','C','D','Y','I'},
                            {'R','C','C','A','E','H','S','E','E','W','N','U','E','T','A'},
                            {'I','I','I','S','O','N','W','D','D','O','O','L','O','H','N'},
                            {'C','T','N','L','E','H','S','O','H','R','L','E','U','O','J'},
                            {'I','A','E','P','I','R','A','M','O','C','I','S','T','L','I'},
                            {'M','N','R','T','A','E','L','D','E','R','S','P','O','O','L'},
                            {'E','E','E','E','N','R','E','T','T','A','P','A','T','G','I'},
                            {'S','V','B','L','A','C','K','H','O','L','E','S','O','Y','N'},  };                      
        for(int i = 0; i <= 14; i++)
        {
             for(int j = 0; j <= 14; j++)
             {
                 System.out.print(maze[i][j] + " ");
             }
             System.out.println();
        }
        String input = kboard.nextLine();

        //checking the word search horizontally

        for(int r = 0; r <= maze.length - 1; r++)
        {
            for(int c = 0; c <= (maze.length - input.length()); c++)
            {
                boolean match = true;
                for(int i=0; i<input.length(); i++)
                {
                    if(maze[r][c + i] != input.charAt(i))
                    {
                        match = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(match)
                {
                    System.out.print("Found match (horizontal) for " + input + " starting at (" + r + ", " + c + ")");
                }
            }
        }

        //checking the word search backwards horizontally

        for(int r = 0; r < maze.length - 1; r++)
        {
            for(int c = 0; c <= (maze.length + 3 - input.length()); c++)
            {
                boolean match = true;
                for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++)
                {
                    if(maze[r][c - i] != input.charAt(i))
                    {
                        match = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(match)
                {
                    System.out.print("Found match (backwards horizontal) for " + input + " starting at (" + r + ", " + c + ")");
                }
            }
        }

        //checking the word search diagonally down

        for(int r = 0; r < maze.length - 1; r++)
        {
            for(int c = 0; c <= (maze.length - input.length()); c++)
            {
                boolean match = true;
                for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++)
                {
                    if(maze[r + i][c + i] != input.charAt(i))
                    {
                        match = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(match)
                {
                    System.out.print("Found match (diagonal down) for " + input + " starting at (" + r + ", " + c + ")");
                }
            }
        }

        //searching the word search diagonally up

        for(int r = 0; r < maze.length - 1; r++)
        {
            for(int c = 0; c <= (maze.length - input.length()); c++)
            {
                boolean match = true;
                for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++)
                {
                    if(maze[r - i][c - i] != input.charAt(i))
                    {
                        match = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(match)
                {
                    System.out.print("Found match (diagonal up) for " + input + " starting at (" + r + ", " + c + ")");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Ive tried numbers and keep getting errors like

```
Found match (horizontal) for BLACKHOLE starting at (14, 2)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1 at WordSearch.main(WordSearch.java:112)`
```

Also, is it bad to use the same for loop each time? Do i only need to change the one line in the third for loop of each one?

Comment: Javascript !== Java

Comment: This is not JavaScript

Comment: What is on line 112?

Comment: Btw, you should also check for diagonal up right and diagonal down left directions. The code you have now only checks the diagonal up left and diagonal down right directions.

Comment: It's not very clear what you're trying to do here. Can you try giving more details or rephrase what you already wrote?

Comment: I found the magic number 3: `for(int c = 0; c <= (maze.length + 3 - input.length()); c++)` - what's it's purpose, where does it come from? Btw.: Blocks of code can often be refactored to a Method, carrying the keyword of a comment, like diagonalUp. Then, 4 tests start the same way - that can be refactored to a common method, calling 4 submethods with parameter 'r', The 4 messages are also looking similar; direction, searchword, r, c.

Answer (score 0):

This line is causing issues:

```
                if(maze[r - i][c - i] != input.charAt(i))
```

Because the loop only increments i and c, r remains at 0, so 0 - 1 = -1, hence out of bounds.

Adjusting to:

```
                if(maze[r][c - i] != input.charAt(i))
```

Stops the out of bounds error, and the loops seem to go through all the columns of each row when searching "BLACK", but doesn't make diagonally searching work well.

You don't ask for different approaches, but you could try going from every point on the grid in all directions, and catching/ignore any outofbounds exceptions, since you know they will be false results, just a thought.